# Transposing columns to rows in impala

Tags: hive, impala

i have following three tables

```
tab_2016
+-----+------+---------+
|  id | month| salary  |
+-----+------+---------+
| 002 |  aug |  500    |
| 002 |  sep |  400    |
+-----+------+---------+


tab_2017    
+-----+------+---------+
|  id | month| salary  |
+-----+------+---------+
| 001 |  jan | 1000    |
| 001 |  jul | 2000    |
| 002 |  aug |  500    |
| 002 |  sep |  400    |
+-----+------+---------+

tab_2018    
+-----+------+---------+
|  id | month| salary  |
+-----+------+---------+
| 001 |  feb | 500     |
| 001 |  jul | 400     |
| 002 |  aug | 300     |
| 002 |  sep | 400     |
+-----+------+---------+
```

I am trying to get the total salary of id : 001 by year in one row as follows.

```
    +-----+---------+---------+-----------+
    |  id | YR_2017 | YR_2018 |  YR_2016  | 
    +-----+---------+---------+-----------+
    | 001 |  3000   | 900     |    0      |
    +-----+---------+---------+-----------+
```

I have tried following query using the case statements but couldn't get the desirable results.I have tried using joins either but when number of tables increases, dynamically forming the query based on the years is getting trickier.

```
    select id,
    case 
    when YR=2017
    then
    sal end as YR_2017,
    case 
    when YR=2018
    then
    sal end as YR_2018,
case 
    when YR=2016
    then
    sal end as YR_2016

 from 
    (select id,sum(salary) as sal,"2017" as YR   from tab_2017 where id=001 group by id
    union all
    select id,sum(salary) as  sal,"2018" as YR from tab_2018 where id=001 group by id
     union all
select id,sum(salary) as  sal,"2016" as YR from tab_2016 where id=001 group by id
) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, a.YR_2017, b.YR_2018, If(c.YR_2016 IS NULL,0,c.YR_2016 ) from (select id,sum(salary) as YR_2017   from tab_2017 where id=1 group by id) a
JOIN (select id,sum(salary) as YR_2018 from tab_2018 where id=1 group by id) b
on a.id=b.id
LEFT JOIN (select id,sum(salary) as YR_2016 from tab_2016 where id=1 group by id) c
on b.id=c.id;
```

This is rough query I haven't tested

Comment: Thanks for answering!But when the sum is zero from the table,then the join condition won't hold.